# How to make a P2SH-P2WPKH output using bitcoin-cli?

Tags: transactions, segregated-witness, p2sh-p2wpkh

Can you give a simple step-by-step example on how to create a transaction with an output of P2SH-P2WPKH using bitcoin-cli on Regtest?

Comment: By P2SH-P2WPKH transaction, you mean a transaction that has such an output, or has an input spending such an output?

Comment: Thx, I modified the question to clarify that is a transaction with such an output

Answer (score -1):

For this example, we will use a transaction that spends two outputs from a previous transaction. The first output (1N2) is paid to the pubkey script "P2SH-P2WPKH" and the second output (1N3) is paid to the pubkey script "P2SH".

1. Create the first transaction that spends the two outputs from a previous transaction. In this example, the first output (1N2) is paid to the pubkey script "P2SH-P2WPKH" and the second output (1N3) is paid to the pubkey script "P2SH".

bitcoin-cli sendtoaddress 1N2 P2SH-P2WPKH
bitcoin-cli sendtoaddress 1N3 P2SH

2. Get the hex encoded transaction data for the first transaction.

bitcoin-cli gettransaction 1N2

Comment: you might want to use markup and/or example values or otherwise somehow make it more clear what strings in your answer are variables, flags, commands, etc

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).